# Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'

Tags: android, android-studio

I was trying to run a simple app in android studio. but it shows below one and stop the execution

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check your app gradle file for any deprecated dependencies. I was struggling with same error today.
My fix was to remove the kotlin-android-extension plugins from the gradle file and add the following code into the gradle file.

```
   buildFeatures{
        viewBinding = true
    }
```

After this, you would need to sync the project again. Additionally, you can do maven clean and then maven build.
With this, my error disappear.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).